# Is thermal impedance defined similar to electrical impedance?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, circuit-analysis, impedance, thermal

[Wiki:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) "Impedance defined in terms of jω can strictly be applied only to circuits that are driven with a steady-state AC signal"

I guess the thermal impedance is also defined similarly. Instead of sine wave, here we have periodic square pulses of varying duty cycle and frequency.
[image]

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11158.pdf

The term 'transient' thermal impedance seems to be minor misnomer. Is it correct?
The above graph looks like a steady - phenomenon just like capacitive/inductive impedances are steady state parameters.

Edit (To clarify the above statement): The impedance/reactance concept cannot be used to calculate the transient response in an AC circuit. Rather it helps to calculate the steady state AC response after the initial transients die out.

Mostly the appnote might have loosely used the term transient to denote anything other than DC?

Comment: Here's a nice explanation of transient thermal impedance and what it means to temperature rise (which is what we care about).https://eepower.com/technical-articles/understanding-the-theory-behind-transient-thermal-impedance/#

Comment: The term "transient thermal impedance" is, In my mind, a tautology (use of the same thing twice over in different words), because the term "thermal impedance" itself implies a transient characteristic, or phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal circuits have electrical analogues, so you can analyze them using the same tools.

When modeling a thermal circuit using an electrical circuit,

- absolute temperature is equivalent to voltage relative to the zero node,
- thermal mass is equivalent to capacitance,
- heat sources/sinks are equivalent to current source/sinks,
- thermal resistances are equivalent to electrical resistances.

> The term 'transient' thermal impedance seems to be minor misnomer. Is it correct?

Not necessarily. Transient means non-DC, so you need *complex impedance*, and not merely real resistance. So while the language is a bit unnecessarily convoluted, it points in the right direction.

The biggest problem though is that they're using transient impedance to really mean complex impedance at a given frequency (inverse of a time constant). The actual circuit being modeled is a cascade of R-C stages, each with its own time constant, with transient behavior as observed.

Answer (score 0):

" Instead of sine wave, here we have periodic square pulses "

Well, no. Or at least not necessarily. Thermal impedance is usually dealt with by use of rectangular pulses, but that's just because we ordinarily worry about temperature as a desired steady state, and (in modern practice) it's much easier and more efficient to provide heat by means of such bursts. But it's not necessary.

And "transient" simply means "changing". The illustration you've provided simply shows how themal impedance changes with time for different heating profiles.The reason the thermal impedance changes is that the mounting structure has different parts which heat up at different rates. So, while all the parts are heating up, the impedance is low. When some parts have reached equilibrium they cannot "accept" any more heat, and the effect of the other, slower-to-heat parts becomes dominant as a higher impedance overall.

Comment: There are many systems that never reach a steady state temperature, as they are always operating (dissipating power) is  dis-continuous fashion.

Comment: True, but generally they operate within a specified error band around a fixed target temperature.

Answer (score 0):

> The term 'transient' thermal impedance seems to be minor misnomer. Is it correct?

It's correct.

> "Impedance defined in terms of jω can strictly be applied only to circuits that are driven with a steady-state AC signal"

This is a bit of a craptacular mishmash (like most of Wikipedia), but it does make a point: if something isn't a sine wave, you probably shouldn't be describing it in terms of angular frequency (ω). Well, what the app note is talking about isn't a sine wave, *and* it's not described in terms of angular frequency, so we're fine.

> The above graph looks like a steady - phenomenon just like capacitive/inductive impedances are steady state parameters.

I'm not really sure what you mean by that, but capacitive/inductive impedances govern the *transient response* of a system, in a way that resistive impedances don't. If you make a step change to the voltage across some part and V/I stays the same, then it's a perfect resistor. If V/I changes for a while and then returns to its original value, then your part has a capacitive or inductive component.

> Mostly the appnote might have loosely used the term transient to denote anything other than DC?

Mostly the appnote might have used the term transient to denote transient, as in "not lasting, temporary, brief" (Oxford English Dictionary).